# Need to check 500 Titles in 5 pages (Each page contains 100 Titles) and each title has to click and check particular heading on that page title

Tags: java, selenium

Checking 500 titles in 5 pages and check heading on each title :
Let me know the corrections please

```
WebElement value = driver.findElement(By.id("numberOfResults"));
Select selectElement = new Select(value);
selectElement.selectByValue("100");

List<WebElement> PostTitles = driver.findElements(By.className("hlFld-Title"));

for (WebElement eachTitle : PostTitles)
{
    System.out.println(eachTitle.getText());
    // String Titles = eachTitle.getText();

    int Size = PostTitles.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < eachTitle; i++)
    {
        driver.findElement(By.linkText(eachTitle.getText())).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("HEADING")).click();
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        driver.navigate().back();
        driver.navigate().back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Completely new and you have to write Selenium tests? Also what is your problem?
You might want to read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237

Comment: So whats wrong with your code and clearly mention what you need not the complete code.

Comment: Hi Chandra Shekar: Printing only first Title and able to check Heading inside that title

Comment: Share a link to the page?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what your scenario is exactly but I think this will work.

A couple corrections:

1. You only need to set `.implicitlyWait()` once and it applies to the life of the `WebDriver`.
2. I think your nested loop was the issue. You are already looping through the titles... just use `eachTitle`.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // this only needs to be set once
WebElement value = driver.findElement(By.id("numberOfResults"));
Select selectElement = new Select(value);
selectElement.selectByValue("100");

List<WebElement> PostTitles = driver.findElements(By.className("hlFld-Title"));
for (WebElement eachTitle : PostTitles)
{
    String title = eachTitle.getText();
    System.out.println(title);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(title)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("HEADING")).click();
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    driver.navigate().back();
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) 
{
WebElement value = driver.findElement(By.id("numberOfResults"));
Select selectElement = new  Select(value);
selectElement.selectByValue("100");
List<WebElement> postTitles = driver.findElements(By.className("hlFld-Title"));
for(int i = 0; i < postTitles.size(); i++) {
    system.out.println(postTitles.get(i).getText());
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(postTitles.get(i).getText())).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("HEADING")).click();
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    driver.navigate().back();
    driver.navigate().back(); 
}
```

Comment: After modifications, I prepared this one. Friends please have a look

Comment: Error :  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Answer (score 0):

**Implemented this logic , Successfully executed, with No Errors**

```
List<WebElement> linkElements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("************"));
String[] linkTitles = new String[linkElements.size()];
int i = 0;
//extract the link texts of each link element
for (WebElement e : linkElements) 
{
    linkTitles[i] = e.getText();
    i++;
}
//Test each link
for (String t : linkTitles) 
{
    // Titles Click 
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(t)).click();
    System.out.println("\n"+ driver.getTitle());
    Thread.sleep(7000);
   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Heading Notes")).click();
   System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("*****")).getText());
   System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
   driver.navigate().back();
   driver.navigate().back();
   Thread.sleep(7000);
}
```